# Power BI Countif between two tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I am a novice in Power BI DAX syntax writing and am desperate for assistance on a problem at work.

Here's the short of it: I have one table which has the RAW data being pulled from Smartsheet. I have a second table I made for a weighted calculation which I cannot figure out how to write.

In this other table I made, I'll call it WEIGHTEDTABLE, I have a [Brand] column with text I typed in when I made the table (Brand1, Brand2, etc). Then I have two columns which I would like to populate with a formula. These two other columns are for Item1 and Item2.

The reason behind this is I can have a graph with just counts of Item1 and Item2 for each brand, but that is not fair/accurate because some brands have more of an item than another (which is why I want to created a WEIGHTED table).

The graph I want to create would have the Brands on the Axis, and the values would be the COUNT of Item1 and Item2 / the appropriate number that I will enter (let's just say it's 25 for Item1 and 10 for Item2).

So ideally, it would be a COUNTIF or IF - if [Brand] from the RAW table = [Brand] from the table I entered, then there would be a COUNT of Item1 from the RAW table divided ( / ) by a 25 or 10.

That's it! Perhaps there is a much easier way to do this. Anything helps and I really appreciate the time and effort that goes into responses!